# Uploading multiple files with Multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to upload multiple images using Multer. It all works as expected except that only one file is being uploaded (the last file selected).

HTML

```
<form class='new-project' action='/projects' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for='file'>Select your image:</label>
  <input type='file' multiple='multiple' accept='image/*' name='uploadedImages' id='file' />
  <span class='hint'>Supported files: jpg, jpeg, png.</span>
  <button type='submit'>upload</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
//Define where project photos will be stored
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (request, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (request, file, callback) {
    console.log(file);
    callback(null, file.originalname)
  }
});

// Function to upload project images
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).any('uploadedImages');

// add new photos to the DB
app.post('/projects', function(req, res){
  upload(req, res, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(req.files);
    res.end('Your files uploaded.');
    console.log('Yep yep!');
  });
});
```

I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious...

**EDIT**

Code I tried following Syed's help:

HTML

```
<label for='file'>Select your image:</label>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' name='uploadedImages' multiple/>
<span class='hint'>Supported files: jpg, jpeg, png.</span>
<input type="submit" value="uploading_img">
```

JS

```
multer = require('multer'),

var upload = multer();

app.post('/projects', upload.array('uploadedImages', 10), function(req, res, err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(err);
  }
  var file = req.files;
  res.end();
  console.log(req.files);
});
```

Answer (score 24):

## Uploading multiple files with Multer

### NodeJs Code

Set require **files** and **Storage**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './images/'))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + file.originalname.match(/\..*$/)[0])
    }
});
```

Set upload file **limit** or **validataion**

```
const multi_upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 1MB
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            const err = new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!')
            err.name = 'ExtensionError'
            return cb(err);
        }
    },
}).array('uploadedImages', 2)
```

Create the main route for **uploading**

```
app.post('/projects', (req, res) => {
    multi_upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            res.status(500).send({ error: { message: `Multer uploading error: ${err.message}` } }).end();
            return;
        } else if (err) {
            // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
            if (err.name == 'ExtensionError') {
                res.status(413).send({ error: { message: err.message } }).end();
            } else {
                res.status(500).send({ error: { message: `unknown uploading error: ${err.message}` } }).end();
            }
            return;
        }

        // Everything went fine.
        // show file `req.files`
        // show body `req.body`
        res.status(200).end('Your files uploaded.');
    })
});
```

Listen **port**

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

### HTML code

```
<form id="form_el" class='new-project' action='/projects' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for='file'>Select your image:</label>
    <input type='file' multiple='multiple' accept='image/*' name='uploadedImages' id='file' />
    <span class='hint'>Supported files: jpg, jpeg, png.</span>
    <button type='submit'>upload</button>
</form>
```

### JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
form_el.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    const files = e.target.uploadedImages.files;
    if (files.length != 0) {
        for (const single_file of files) {
            data.append('uploadedImages', single_file)
        }
    }
});

const submit_data_fetch = await fetch('/projects', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been fighting with this for the last 4 hours. The individual appends was what I was searching for.

Comment: thank you, here is how to use the `multer().array()` method: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount

Comment: in the callback filename you change the originalfilename (with Date.now().. ) and save it to the disk, but how can I get that new name further in my route? since req.files has still the original file names and not the new ones set by you!

Answer (score 13):

Here you go for this example:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

router.post('/projects', upload.array('uploadedImages', 10), function(req, res) {
  var file = req.files;
  res.end();
});
```

```
<form action="/projects" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="uploadedImages" value="uploading_img" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="uploading_img">
</form>
```

Visit for more info about [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Thanks Syed, but I just tried this and get this error in console: error
`[Function: next]
[ { fieldname: 'uploadedImages',
    originalname: 'Me.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff fe 00 04 2a 00 ff e2 02 1c 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 0c 6c 63 ... >,
    size: 98305 } ]`

Comment: Have you tried only my example or apply your code as well ?

Comment: I just added the code I tried to my original post. Same as yours more or less, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that for each file that you want to upload, you reclick:

```
<input type='file' multiple='multiple' accept='image/*' name='uploadedImages' id='file' />
```

If you do this, then only the last file selected will be uploaded, as you overwrite the previous selected files.

To upload multiple files, you have to select them all at once in the file picker.

Comment: Hey your answer helped me, just need to ask what if i want the user to upload every file on click, how could i then prevent this default behaviour?