# How do I upload multiple files to AWS S3 at once using mongoDB, react, and express?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, multer

I am already able to upload video files to AWS S3, but I want to also have the user upload a thumbnail img along with the video they select to upload. Is there a way to upload multiple files at once using multer and mongoDB?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBcLK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FpVH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXBED.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ8Ml.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can! first, you must use `upload.array('file', 2)` in your api(the 2 here is the number of files to upload), and in your react code you need an input that accepts multiple files, like this: `<input type='file' multiple='multiple' />`

One important step is to make the post as **multipart/form-data** and send the array of files to the server, maybe in your `handleChange` function you can do this: `this.setState({[key]: e.target.files });` to send all files at once. One last thing, maybe you want to store just the url to the file in your mongodb, if so, then change the type to string, `file: {type: String}` and `thumbnail: {type: String}`. Hope i clarified the things a bit!

some good references for you:

[Uploading multiple files with Multer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350040/uploading-multiple-files-with-multer)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks for responding! Just tried doing what you suggested and file is now coming back as undefined. Im very new to react, aws, and stackoverflow. How can I share my screenshots with you?

Comment: You're welcome! but please, try to post your question as complete as possible that way i can help you more, edit your question and add your code with the code sample tool, screenshots aren't helpful. I also need to see the code where you are getting the files from the user and the code where you are making the api call, like axios or fetch.